# R Leaflet: Passing popupOptions when adding Polygons.

Tags: r, leaflet

Within `addPolygons()` there is a `popup` parameter just like the one in the `addPopups()` function.  The difference (I think) is that when the popup is created within `addPolygons()`, one can click anywhere within the polygon to trigger the popup, but if `addPopups()` is used, a single `lng` and `lat` point must be defined.

I want to change one of the default options (`maxWidth`) in `popupOptions()` which can easily be done when using `addPopups()` because it contains the parameter `options = popupOptions()` but I don't know how to do it when using `addPolygons()`; within that function the options parameter is `options = pathOptions()`.

Below is a reproducible example from the leaflet documentation with a popup added that I'd like increase the `maxWidth`.

```
library(rgdal)

# From https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/cbf/cbf_state.html
states <- readOGR("shp/cb_2013_us_state_20m.shp",
  layer = "cb_2013_us_state_20m", verbose = FALSE)

neStates <- subset(states, states$STUSPS %in% c(
  "CT","ME","MA","NH","RI","VT","NY","NJ","PA"
))

leaflet(neStates) %>%
  addPolygons(
    stroke = FALSE, fillOpacity = 0.5, smoothFactor = 0.5,
    color = ~colorQuantile("YlOrRd", states$AWATER)(AWATER),
    popup="<b>Hello World</b>"
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Currently not possible, though already implemented as a pull request. See here https://github.com/rstudio/leaflet/issues/258

Answer (score 2):

You can do this simply by adding `popupOptions()` after your popup in the `addPloygons()` block like so:

```
leaflet(neStates) %>%
    addPolygons(
        stroke = FALSE, fillOpacity = 0.5, smoothFactor = 0.5,
        color = ~colorQuantile("YlOrRd", states$AWATER)(AWATER),
        popup="<b>Hello World</b>"
        popupOptions = popupOptions(maxWidth ="100%", closeOnClick = TRUE)
```

)

Here is the list from the PDF vignette on leaflet R of all the things you can drop in the `popupOptions()` list:

```
popupOptions(maxWidth = 300, minWidth = 50, maxHeight = NULL,
            autoPan = TRUE, keepInView = FALSE, closeButton = TRUE,
             zoomAnimation = TRUE, closeOnClick = NULL, className = "", ...)
```