# clickable overlying layers in leaflet

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I use leaflet+shiny in R. I display neighbourhoods in a choropleth map together with borders (i.e. `fillColor = "transparent"`) of regions. Each region contains several neighbourhoods, so the layers overlap (neighborhoods are in the background). I struggle to make neighbourhoods clickable (e.g. to invoke popups). Could you advise me how to do it please?

The code I use looks like this:

```
leaflet()  %>%
  addPolygons (data = neighborhood.shp, #displaying variables
              stroke = TRUE,
              fillColor = ~fillVar,
              color = "#000000",
              popup = "click"
              weight=1) %>% 
  addPolygons (data = region.shp, #showing borders
              color = "#FFFFFF",
              weight=5,                                                     
              fillOpacity = 0,
              fillColor = "transparent")
```

Thank you!

Comment: try setting `fill = FALSE` in your second `addPolygons` call.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example... Is [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37820196/r-leaflet-passing-popupoptions-when-adding-polygons) related?

Comment: @TimSalabim thak you! setting `fill = FALSE` worked!

Comment: @TimSalabim consider putting that in an answer :)

Comment: @chrki good point!

Answer (score 1):

Setting `fill = FALSE` in your second `addPolygons` call should make the underlying polygons layer queryable/clickable:

```
leaflet()  %>%
  addPolygons (data = neighborhood.shp, #displaying variables
              stroke = TRUE,
              fillColor = ~fillVar,
              color = "#000000",
              popup = "click"
              weight=1) %>% 
  addPolygons (data = region.shp, #showing borders
              color = "#FFFFFF",
              weight=5,
              fill = FALSE)
```